Filter & Copy, Paste Data in New Excel File From Branch List Sheet & Save That Same in Folder with VBA Loop
I want to filter and split the data based on branch name (Branch List sheet), and also want to save that new  excel workbook for each branch as per the same name as mentioned in the Branch List sheet. Please help me with LOOP function to complete my code.

Below is the my code.
Sub Split_Branch()

' Split_Branch Macro

LastCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Branch_List").Cells(Rows.Count, 
1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Branch_List").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AMALNER SME"
Sheets("All Products Due List").Select
Range("B1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$500000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
    "AMALNER SME"
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Range("A3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("B2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AMALNER SME"
Range("A1").Select
ChDir "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Split Branch DATA"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Split Branch DATA\AMALNER SME.xlsx", 
FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
   
End Sub

I Tried but unable to loop, based on Branch list.
